# How can I publish the same collection with different subsets of data?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have collection called Rooms, now, I want to publish different subsets of Room depending on where the user is on the app, so, this is what I had in mind:

```
  Meteor.publish('roomList', function() {
    return Rooms.find({}, {fields: {'roomId': 1, 'playerCount': 1, 'isPlaying': 1}});
  });

  Meteor.publish('roomInfo', function(_id) {
    return Rooms.find({_id: _id}, {fields: {'players': 1}});
  })

  Meteor.publish('roomGame', function(_id) {
    return Rooms.find({_id: _id}, {fields: {'game': 1}});
  })
```

I don't want to throttle the connection sending players info when the user is just browsing rooms, however, when a user enters a room, I want to subscribe him to roomInfo so he can see who's in the room, and when the room is playing, subscribe to roomGame which contains game info.
This is how I subscribe(at this point, user is already subscribed to roomList).

```
  Router.route('/sala/:_id', {
    name: 'roomLobby',
    waitOn: function() {
      return this.subscribe('roomInfo', this.params._id);
    },
    data:function(){
      var r = Rooms.findOne(this.params._id);
      console.log(r.players);
      return r;
    }
  });
```

However, r.players always come up as undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work if you replace `this.subscribe` with `Meteor.subscribe`?

Comment: It still returns undefined.

Comment: may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632452/publishing-subscribing-multiple-subsets-of-the-same-server-collection/12684186

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route logic looks pretty good. I would change only a couple of things:

```
Router.route('/sala/:_id', {
    name: 'roomLobby',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('roomInfo', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() {
        if(this.ready()) {
            var r = Rooms.findOne(this.params._id);
            console.log(r.players);
            return r;
        }
    }
});
```

The first thing that I changed is to use `Meteor.subscribe()` instead of `this.subscribe()` in your `waitOn` route option definition. This is the prescribed way to define a subscription handle in a `waitOn` route option definition per the documentation [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option).

The second thing that I changed is to wrap all of your code in the `data` route option definition in an `if(this.ready()){}` statement. Per documentation [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready), the `this.ready()` call is tied directly into and reacts to the wait list for the route, which is filled as you define one or more `Meteor.subscribe()` calls in your `waitOn` route option definition.