# How efficient can Meteor be while sharing a huge collection among many clients?

Tags: benchmarking, meteor

Imagine the following case:

- 1,000 clients are connected to a Meteor page displaying the content of the "Somestuff" collection.
- "Somestuff" is a collection holding 1,000 items.
- Someone inserts a new item into the "Somestuff" collection

What will happen:

- All `Meteor.Collection`s on clients will be updated i.e. the insertion forwarded to all of them (which means one insertion message sent to 1,000 clients)

What is the cost in term of CPU for the server to determine which client needs to be updated?

Is it accurate that only the inserted value will be forwarded to the clients, and not the whole list?

How does this work in real life? Are there any benchmarks or experiments of such scale available?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The short answer is that only new data gets sent down the wire.  Here's
how it works.

There are three important parts of the Meteor server that manage
subscriptions: the *publish function*, which defines the logic for what
data the subscription provides; the *Mongo driver*, which watches the
database for changes; and the *merge box*, which combines all of a
client's active subscriptions and sends them out over the network to the
client.

#### Publish functions

Each time a Meteor client subscribes to a collection, the server runs a
*publish function*.  The publish function's job is to figure out the set
of documents that its client should have and send each document property
into the merge box.  It runs once for each new subscribing client.  You
can put any JavaScript you want in the publish function, such as
arbitrarily complex access control using `this.userId`.  The publish
function sends data into the merge box by calling `this.added`, `this.changed` and
`this.removed`.  See the
[full publish documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) for
more details.

Most publish functions don't have to muck around with the low-level
`added`, `changed` and `removed` API, though.  If a publish function returns a Mongo
cursor, the Meteor server automatically connects the output of the Mongo
driver (`insert`, `update`, and `removed` callbacks) to the input of the
merge box (`this.added`, `this.changed` and `this.removed`).  It's pretty neat
that you can do all the permission checks up front in a publish function and
then directly connect the database driver to the merge box without any user
code in the way.  And when autopublish is turned on, even this little bit is
hidden: the server automatically sets up a query for all documents in each
collection and pushes them into the merge box.

On the other hand, you aren't limited to publishing database queries.
For example, you can write a publish function that reads a GPS position
from a device inside a `Meteor.setInterval`, or polls a legacy REST API
from another web service.  In those cases, you'd emit changes to the
merge box by calling the low-level `added`, `changed` and `removed` DDP API.

#### The Mongo driver

The *Mongo driver's* job is to watch the Mongo database for changes to
live queries.  These queries run continuously and return updates as the
results change by calling `added`, `removed`, and `changed` callbacks.

Mongo is not a real time database.  So the driver polls.  It keeps an
in-memory copy of the last query result for each active live query.  On
each polling cycle, it compares the new result with the previous saved
result, computing the minimum set of `added`, `removed`, and `changed`
events that describe the difference.  If multiple callers register
callbacks for the same live query, the driver only watches one copy of
the query, calling each registered callback with the same result.

Each time the server updates a collection, the driver recalculates each
live query on that collection (Future versions of Meteor will expose a
scaling API for limiting which live queries recalculate on update.)  The
driver also polls each live query on a 10 second timer to catch
out-of-band database updates that bypassed the Meteor server.

#### The merge box

The job of the *merge box* is to combine the results (`added`, `changed` and `removed`
calls) of all of a client's active publish functions into a single data
stream.  There is one merge box for each connected client.  It holds a
complete copy of the client's minimongo cache.

In your example with just a single subscription, the merge box is
essentially a pass-through.  But a more complex app can have multiple
subscriptions which might overlap.  If two subscriptions both set the
same attribute on the same document, the merge box decides which value
takes priority and only sends that to the client.  We haven't exposed
the API for setting subscription priority yet.  For now, priority is
determined by the order the client subscribes to data sets.  The first
subscription a client makes has the highest priority, the second
subscription is next highest, and so on.

Because the merge box holds the client's state, it can send the minimum
amount of data to keep each client up to date, no matter what a publish
function feeds it.

#### What happens on an update

So now we've set the stage for your scenario.

We have 1,000 connected clients.  Each is subscribed to the same live
Mongo query (`Somestuff.find({})`).  Since the query is the same for each client, the driver is
only running one live query.  There are 1,000 active merge boxes.  And
each client's publish function registered an `added`, `changed`, and
`removed` on that live query that feeds into one of the merge boxes.
Nothing else is connected to the merge boxes.

First the Mongo driver.  When one of the clients inserts a new document
into `Somestuff`, it triggers a recomputation.  The Mongo driver reruns
the query for all documents in `Somestuff`, compares the result to the
previous result in memory, finds that there is one new document, and
calls each of the 1,000 registered `insert` callbacks.

Next, the publish functions.  There's very little happening here: each
of the 1,000 `insert` callbacks pushes data into the merge box by
calling `added`.

Finally, each merge box checks these new attributes against its
in-memory copy of its client's cache.  In each case, it finds that the
values aren't yet on the client and don't shadow an existing value.  So
the merge box emits a DDP `DATA` message on the SockJS connection to its
client and updates its server-side in-memory copy.

Total CPU cost is the cost to diff one Mongo query, plus the cost of
1,000 merge boxes checking their clients' state and constructing a new
DDP message payload.  The only data that flows over the wire is a single
JSON object sent to each of the 1,000 clients, corresponding to the new
document in the database, plus one RPC message *to the server* from the
client that made the original insert.

#### Optimizations

Here's what we definitely have planned.

- More efficient Mongo driver.  We
  [optimized the driver](http://meteor.com/blog/2012/11/20/meteor-051-database-scaling)
  in 0.5.1 to only run a single observer per distinct query.
- Not every DB change should trigger a recomputation of a query.  We
  can make some automated improvements, but the best approach is an API
  that lets the developer specify which queries need to rerun.  For
  example, it's obvious to a developer that inserting a message into
  one chatroom should not invalidate a live query for the messages in a
  second room.
- The Mongo driver, publish function, and merge box don't need to run
  in the same process, or even on the same machine.  Some applications
  run complex live queries and need more CPU to watch the database.
  Others have only a few distinct queries (imagine a blog engine), but
  possibly many connected clients -- these need more CPU for merge
  boxes.  Separating these components will let us scale each piece
  independently.
- Many databases support triggers that fire when a row is updated and
  provide the old and new rows.  With that feature, a database driver
  could register a trigger instead of polling for changes.

Comment: Is there any example on how to use Meteor.publish to publish non-cursor data? Such as results from a legacy rest API mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @Tony: It is in documentation. Check the room counting example.

Comment: It is worth noting that in releases 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2 Meteor switched to OpLog Observe Driver for the most queries (exceptions are `skip`, `$near` and `$where` containing queries) which is far more efficient in CPU load, network bandwidth and allows scaling out application servers.

Comment: What about when not every user sees the same data. 1. they subscribed to different topics .2. they have different roles so within same main topic, there are a few messages that are not supposed to reach them.

Comment: @debergalis regarding cache invalidation, perhaps you'll find ideas from my paper http://vanisoft.pl/~lopuszanski/public/cache_invalidation.pdf worthwhile

Comment: But on each start of the app/website ALL data has to be sent to the user, right? The change itself is small compared to the starting-load.

Answer (score 29):

From my experience, using many clients with while sharing a huge collection in Meteor is essentially unworkable, as of version 0.7.0.1. I'll try to explain why.

As described in the above post and also in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1821, the meteor server has to keep a copy of the published data for each client in the **merge box**. This is what allows the Meteor magic to happen, but also results in any large shared databases being repeatedly kept in the memory of the node process. Even when using a possible optimization for static collections such as in (**[Is there a way to tell meteor a collection is static (will never change)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699022/586086)**), we experienced a huge problem with the CPU and Memory usage of the Node process.

In our case, we were publishing a collection of 15k documents to each client that was completely static. The problem is that copying these documents to a client's merge box (in memory) upon connection basically brought the Node process to 100% CPU for almost a second, and resulted in a large additional usage of memory. This is inherently unscalable, because any connecting client will bring the server to its knees (and simultaneous connections will block each other) and memory usage will go up linearly in the number of clients. In our case, each client caused an additional **~60MB** of memory usage, even though the raw data transferred was only about 5MB.

In our case, because the collection was static, we solved this problem by sending all the documents as a `.json` file, which was gzipped by nginx, and loading them into an anonymous collection, resulting in only a ~1MB transfer of data with no additional CPU or memory in the node process and a much faster load time. All operations over this collection were done by using `_id`s from much smaller publications on the server, allowing for retaining most of the benefits of Meteor. This allowed the app to scale to many more clients. In addition, because our app is mostly read-only, we further improved the scalability by running multiple Meteor instances behind nginx with load balancing (though with a single Mongo), as each Node instance is single-threaded.

However, the issue of sharing large, writeable collections among multiple clients is an engineering problem that needs to be solved by Meteor. There is probably a better way than keeping a copy of everything for each client, but that requires some serious thought as a distributed systems problem. The current issues of massive CPU and memory usage just won't scale.

Comment: @Harry oplog doesn't matter in this situation; the data was static.

Comment: Why does it not do diffs of the server side minimongo copies? Maybe that's all changed in 1.0? I mean usually they are the same I'd hope, even functions that it calls back would be similar (if I'm following that that to is something that is stored there as well and potentially different.)

Comment: @MistereeDevlord Diffing of changes and caches of client data are separate right now. Even if everyone has the same data and only one diff is needed, the cache per client differs because the server can't treat them identically. This could definitely be done smarter over the existing implementation.

Comment: @AndrewMao How do you make sure the gzipped files are secured when sending them to the client, i.e. only a logged in client can access it?

Answer (score 4):

The experiment that you can use to answer this question:

1. Install a test meteor: `meteor create --example todos`
2. Run it under Webkit inspector (WKI).
3. Examine the contents of the [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) messages moving across the wire.
4. Observe that the entire collection is not moved across the wire.

For tips on how to use WKI check out this [article](http://jtaby.com/2012/04/23/modern-web-development-part-1.html). It's a little out of date, but mostly still valid, especially for this question.

Comment: An explanation of the polling mechanism: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-liveresultsset

Answer (score 3):

This is still a year old now and therefore I think pre-"Meteor 1.0" knowledge, so things may have changed again? I'm still looking into this.
http://meteorhacks.com/does-meteor-scale.html
leads to a "How to scale Meteor?" article
http://meteorhacks.com/how-to-scale-meteor.html