# Meteor server-side memory usage for thousands of concurrent users

Tags: meteor

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867122/1745592), it looks like the meteor server keeps an in-memory copy of the cache for each connected client. My understanding is that it gets used in order to avoid sending multiple copies of data when dealing with overlapping subscriptions on a client.

The relevant part of the linked answer (emphasis is mine):

> The merge box: The job of the merge box is to combine the results (added, changed and removed calls) of all of a client's active publish functions into a single data stream. There is one merge box **for each connected client**. It holds a **complete copy of the client's minimongo cache.**

Assuming that answer is still accurate in the current version of meteor, couldn't that create a huge waste of memory on the server as the number of users increases?

As an off-the-cuff calculation, if an app had about a 100kB cache per client, then 10,000 concurrent users would use up 1GB of memory on the server, and 100,000 users a whopping 10GB! This would be true even if each client was looking at almost identical data. It seems plausible for an app use much more data than that per client, which would further exacerbate the problem.

Does this problem exist in the current version of Meteor? If so, what techniques can be used to limit the amount of memory the server needs to use to manage all the client subscriptions?

Comment: I do not have the answer to your question, however just a quick comment: I think if you were looking at serving 100,000 concurrent users, you'd bottleneck on something else way before that anyway. 10GB is nothing, even the smallest HP DL160 'pizza box' servers can be loaded up with 192GB. Note also that MDG is planning to scale Meteor via something called 'galaxy' - latest update is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/meteor-core/fM50Lbo2D3U

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this post by Arunoda at his meteorhacks.com blog:
http://meteorhacks.com/making-meteor-500-faster-with-smart-collections.html

which talks about his Smart Collections page:
http://meteorhacks.com/introducing-smart-collections.html

He created an alternative Collection stack which has succeeded in it's goals for speed, efficiency (memory & cpu) and scalability (you can see a graphed comparison in the post).  Admittedly in his tests RAM usage was negligent with both Collection types, although the way he's implemented things there should be a very obvious difference with the type of use case you mentioned.

Also, you can see in this post on meteor-core:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-core/jG1KLObX1bM/39aP4kxqWZUJ
that the Meteor developers are aware of his work and are cooperating in implementing some of the improvements into Meteor itself (but until then his smart package works great).

Important note!  Smart collections relies on access to the Mongo Oplog.  This is easy if you're running on your own machine or hosted infrastructure.  If you're using a cloud based database, this option might not be available, or if it is, will cost a lot more than the smaller packages.