# Meteor - Reference error from publish call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to implement a search like in the thread: [Meteor publish/subscribe strategies for unique client-side collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223866/meteor-publish-subscribe-strategies-for-unique-client-side-collections). I have wrapped the function in Meteor.startup as follows, but am still getting a reference error on the getSearchUsers function call.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

    function getSearchUsers(query) {

        var re = new RegExp(query, "i");
        return Users.find({name: {$regex: re}});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the variable scoping. Try to write out the method with a global variable definition:

```
getSearchUsers = function(query) {

    var re = new RegExp(query, "i");
    return Users.find({name: {$regex: re}});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akshat. I have tried this, but am getting the same error

Comment: Ah the server publication needs to be wrapped in Meteor.startup too

Comment: @RhysBartels-Waller it doesn't have to, but if that sorted the problem you also had an issue with file loading order. This getSearchUsers method is defined after your publish function. See http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: getSearchUsers is in /lib/search.js, so shouldn't that load first?

Comment: It depends, where is the file you're running? Is it also in lib with a filename beginning with a letter less than s?

Comment: The publish function call is in /server/publications.js, and getSearchUsers() is in /lib/search.js

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @Akshat Any idea on what's going on?